# Using the formal definition of big O notation, would f(x) not be O(g(x)) for nearly all functions of g(x)?

Tags: limits, asymptotics

The formal definition of big O notation states

$$f(x)=O(g(x)) \text{ as } x \rightarrow \inf \leftrightarrow |f(x)| \leq Mg(x) \text{ for all } x \geq x_0 $$

But would this not mean, for example, when $f(x) = 2x^2$, $f(x) = O(x!)$?

Setting $M=1$ and $x_0 = 5$, shows that $2x^2 \leq x!,\text{ } x \geq 5$.

The problem with this is that it doesn't sound right, and also doesn't follow the set of rules suggested [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Example) that is used to find the big O of a certain function.

My question is whether this is correct, which would mean for any function there are infinite big O functions they are, or if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: This is correct.  $2x^2 = O(x!)$ and also $2x^2 = O(x^2)$.  Note this an abuse of notation of the equals sign; you can't conclude from these two "equations" that $O(x!) = O(x^2)$.  Perhaps we should really say $2x^2 \in O(x!)$, but the usage is standard.

Comment: But generally, we try to find the smallest convenient Big-Oh family for a given function.  You wouldn't normally write $2x^2 = O(x!)$ for the same reason that you wouldn't write $\pi < 10000$ when you can write $\pi < 4$.

Comment: @JairTaylor Thankyou for the answer. Yeh I understand using = isn't correct, it's just that it's used every for this notation. I saw somewhere the best way to think of it is to replace "=" with "is"

Comment: Right.  But the use of $=$ here is not incorrect.  It's correct by convention.  You just have to interpret it correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. For instance if $f \in O(x^n)$ then $f \in O(x^{n+m})$ as well.

Usually when one is asked to show $f \in O(g)$ for some $g$, you want $g$ to grow as slowly as possible. Saying $f \in O(x!)$ is not really helpful because that class is humongous.

There is no "unique" or "best" big-O class for any given $f$, but one usually tries to find the best among $O(g)$ where $g$ is among monomials, logarithms, exponentials, etc.